# D3.JS- Format tick values with an ordinal scale axis

Tags: arrays, d3.js, scale, ordinal

I'm using an ordinal scale in my axis:

```
var xBarScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
    .domain(d3.range(data.length));

var xBarAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xBarScale)
    .orient("bottom");
```

My tick labels are in my data array. What is the best way to format my tick values (using a D3 method) than simply listing each one in the array as I've done here:

```
 xBarAxis.tickValues([data[0].q,data[1].q,data[2].q,data[3].q,data[4].q]);
```

Comment: as you use an ordinal scale, you could push your `data[i].q` values into an array and use this array for the scale: `.domain(_yourarray_)` - then you should be able to omit the `.tickValues` property altogether

Comment: `xBarAxis.tickValues(data.map(function(d) { return d.q; }));`

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm using **`D3 v4`** and this is how I would do it:

```
var xBarScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
    .domain(d3.range(data.length));

var xBarAxis = d3.axisBottom( xBarScale )
    .tickFormat((d)=> d + ' position' ) // just an example of formatting each Tick's text
    .tickValues( data.map(d => d.q) )  // creates an Array of `q` values
```

As to my example, you can set the [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickFormat) to format your text labels however you wish